# How to set hbase_clusters in hue

Tags: hbase, hue

Here is the settings and description in pseudo-distributed.ini, but I have no idea what is the correct value should I fill in the ClusterName field.

## Settings to configure Hbase

[hbase]

# Comma-separated list of HBase Thrift servers for

# clusters in the format of '(name|host:port)'.

hbase_clusters=(***ClusterName***|masterIP:thriftPort)

# Hard limit of rows or columns per row fetched before truncating.

truncate_limit = 500

Answer (score 0):

You can just put any name. The cluster will then show up with this name in the [HBase Browser](http://gethue.tumblr.com/post/59071544309/the-web-ui-for-hbase-hbase-browser).

Comment: But if I put the name other than "Cluster", it will show a message said "Cluster by the name of mCluster does not exist in configuration"